# jQuery - change/add an event on a link

Tags: jquery

I have this link :

```
<a href="#" onClick="addSide('1');return false">Link</a>
```

and I want that, when I click on a button (for example), the value of addSide in that link grow. Such as first click on the button I want to pass to the addSide function 1, second click 
addSide('2'), and so on...

So, is it possible change value of the addSide function, trought jQuery, by editing this and replace with somethings like `addSide('another_value')`?

EDIT
I see is not so clear my question. So I give an example :)

This is the code I want to edit :

```
<div class="trackon" id="trackline">
    <span class="trackbotton1">
        <a class="lblueb" href="#" onClick="addSide('');return false">Add Side</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I wrote this :

```
$('#trackline').find('.trackbotton1').children().attr('onclick', 'alert("example");return false');
```

but the function doesnt change...

Comment: You want the event to change on subsequent clicks of the same link ?

Comment: More information please. More information => better answers.

Comment: Can you modify HTML markup? (Is it under your control?)

Comment: Check the code added on the topic, hope is better :)

Comment: It actually isn't :) Try answering questions and add comments to provided answers.

Comment: If you are using jQuery anyways, would not it be cleaner and easier to stop using those inline event handlers? Don't be your own enemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** This is based on [Jimmy Sawczuk's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671273/jquery-change-add-an-event-on-a-link/5671293#5671293), and it works.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="link" onclick="addSide();return false" rel="1">Link</a>
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="slide">1</div>
```

JS

```
$('#button').click(function() {
 var current_num = parseInt($('#link').attr('rel'));
 var new_num = current_num + 1;
 $('#link').attr('rel', new_num);
});

function addSide() {
    var n = parseInt($('#link').attr('rel'));
    $('#slide').text('slide number ' + n );
}
```

---

**Old answer** - This doesn't work.

```
<a href="#" id="link" onclick="addSide('1');return false">Link</a>
<button id="button">Button</button>

$('#button').click(function() {
 var current_func = $('#link').attr('onclick');
 var current_func_parts  = current_func.split("'");
 var current_num = parseInt(current_func_parts[1]);
 var new_num = current_num + 1;
 var new_func = "addSide('" + new_num + "');return false";
 $('#link').attr('onclick', new_func);
});
```

Comment: This solution looks nice..but it doesnt work on my Page. added the example above...

Comment: This answer does not deserve the upvote. It is broken and does not work. I checked with firebug and found why it fails. It's the `split` line that throws an error, and the reason is, contrary to my expectation current_func is not a string, it is a function. The way to go Jimmy Sawczuk's.

Comment: This is a -1 from me, you took @Jimmy's code and made something uglier out of it, mixing inline and jquery event handling.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Very kind of you ;). I did say my answer (first version) was broken; when I realized this I had two options - delete it, or fix it. I fixed it and made use of Jimmy's approach (not code), gave credit, and upvoted his answer. Inline event handling comes from the question itself and as I wanted to make the least amount of change I didn't alter that, jQuery event handling comes from me, and so the two are mixed. Anyway I fail to see why this is a cardinal sin.

Comment: @Majid My view is that we should not promote bad coding habits. If inline event handling was used in the question, you can still give a better solution. It is much better than mixing the two :). BTW, I haven't even looked at your `Old Answer`, it could be deleted as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would use an event binding like so:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="side_adder" rel="1">Link</a>
```

And then, in your JS:

```
$('.side_adder').click(function(evt)
{
    addSide($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

To change the value passed, simply change the `rel` using `$(selector).attr({'rel': <whatever>});`.

Comment: Yep, that'd work too. I used `rel` because there was only one parameter, but if there were multiple parameters `data` attributes would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend going for [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="canAddSide">Link</a>
```

**JS**

```
var curSide=1;
$('.canAddSide').click(function(event){
    addSide(curSide);
    curSide++;// increment or change the current side
    event.preventDefault();// return false;
});
```